# DNS.GethostEntry Unable to get remote machine ipv6 adress

Tags: c#, dns, ipv6

DNS.GetHostEnt`ry unable to get remote machine ipv6 address

IPv4 address exists in the `IPHostEntry` but ipv6 is missing

```
string hostname = "my-machine";
IPHostEntry ie = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);
```

Image contains 2 address but the 2nd address is not Link-local IPV6 address rather than it is Tunnel Adapter 6T04 address

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing whatever is advertised in DNS. DNS should never contain link-local addresses because the receiver won't be able to know which link they are valid on.

If `20.200.20.24` and `2002:14c8:1418::14c8:1418` are what is in the DNS zone then that is what you will get. If that is not what you want then you are either looking in the wrong place or you should adjust the content of the DNS zone.

PS: are you working for/with CSC? Otherwise you probably shouldn't be using addresses from `20.0.0.0/8`...

Comment: But the Same code is working fine when i specify local-machine name its return local-link address as well

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if your local machine intercepts requests for itself. Otherwise there might be some link-local mDNS (Bonjour) thing going on, but I can't tell from the information in your question.